# How do I fix my code so it runs correctly, it keeps telling me I have Error Code 1055

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to complete this multi-query assignment but cannot figure out why I keep getting this error code (Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ebe.Co.ContactName' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by). This is my code below

```
USE EBE;

SELECT C.ClientName, CO.ContactName, CO.ContactPhone, CO.ContactEmail,
  COUNT(E.EventCode) AS NumberOfEvents
FROM Client AS C 
INNER JOIN Contact AS CO ON C.ClientID = CO.ClientID 
INNER JOIN Events AS E ON C.ClientID = E.ClientID
GROUP BY E.ClientID
ORDER BY C.ClientName;
```

Comment: The error message is pretty much self-explanatory, what exactly can't you figure out? It's telling you the columns in your select that are not being aggregated must be in the `group by`

Comment: When you have a `GROUP BY` clause only the columns in this clause can show up in the SELECT list as they are. Any other column should show up "aggregated" using `SUM()`, `MAX()`, `MIN()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All the columns that are being selected except for the aggregated column need to be in the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT C.ClientName, CO.ContactName, CO.ContactPhone, CO.ContactEmail, 
    COUNT(E.EventCode) AS NumberOfEvents 
FROM Client AS C 
INNER JOIN Contact AS CO ON C.ClientID = CO.ClientID 
INNER JOIN Events AS E ON C.ClientID = E.ClientID 
GROUP BY C.ClientName, CO.ContactName, CO.ContactPhone, CO.ContactEmail
ORDER BY C.ClientName
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing your query to remove the need for `group by` would be to use a *correlated subquery*:

```
select C.ClientName,
  CO.ContactName, 
  CO.ContactPhone,
  CO.ContactEmail,
  (select Count(*) from Events E where E.ClientID = C.ClientID) NumberOfEvents
from Client C
join Contact CO on CO.ClientID = c.ClientID
order by C.ClientName;
```